# Netflix Conductor cleanup workflow data

Tags: java, netflix, netflix-conductor, conductor

I'm using Conductor 2.10.1. The main problem is that we have a scheduled job that on each weekend try to delete old workflows history (older than two weeks) using delete workflow api.

When we check Conductor ui the workflow are deleted but when we check Elasticsearch we found that there are a lot of indexes related to the workflow execution, metrics logs... which result after a period a slowness on the ui and making the disk full.

My request is there any solution to have a complete delete action that remove all related data to the source workflow id. Maybe a script that will clean Elasticsearch indexes.

Comment: This feels rather broad at the moment, but you have a solution in mind - is there value in writing the script that you propose?